# I am confused about semi-minimal algebra and semi-minimal space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

This problem is as following:

Let $A$ be an F-algebra and V be a finite dimensional $A$-space.

1. Show that $V$ is a quotient $A$-space of a direct sum $A^{⊕k}$ of $k$
   copies of $A$, regarded as an $A$-space. In other words, there exists a surjective
   A-space homomorphism:$A^{\oplus k}\to V$.
2. We say that an $A$-space $M$ is semi-minimal if it decomposes into a direct sum
   of of minimal $A$-spaces. Show that if $A$ is semi-minimal as an $A$-space, then
   any A-space V is semi-minimal.

The first problem is easy because we can consider the following map:
$\phi: A^{\oplus k}\to V, (a_1,...,a_k)\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^ka_iv_i, v_i\in V$. But we don't know how to use this argument to show the second argument.

a direct idea is consider $A = A_i^{\oplus k}$, where $A_i$ is minimal $A$-space(its proper subspace only two), then use argument one, I get stucked here.

Comment: I will appreciate it if anyone can recommend some reference book to me.

Comment: Just curious, since I'm also working on exactly the same problem. By the way, if you're looking for reference, you may edit your question to include the "reference-request" tag.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that "$A$-space" means *$A$-module*, and "minimal" means *simple* (a module $M$ is simple if it has precisely two submodules: $0$ and $M$). Then "semi-minimal" is *semi-simple*.

For the first problem, you must first *choose* a *basis* $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ of the vector space $V$ over $F$ (or, more generally, a finite subset that generated $V$ as an $A$-module). Then the map $\phi$ becomes a surjective morphism, as you write.

For the second problem, you can read about semi-simple algebras in any basic book about representation theory of algebras, for example: Erdmann, Holm: *Algebras and Representation Theory* (Springer, 2018).